# SQLite3, PDO, Active Record, and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, codeigniter-2

I'm having problems getting CodeIgniter to work with SQLite3.

Here are my database.php configs:

```
$active_group = 'sqlite';
$query_builder = TRUE;

/* SQLite3 config for PDO */

$db['sqlite'] = array (
    'dsn' => 'sqlite:' .FCPATH.'virtTour_original.sqlite',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

Here's the controller I'm testing with:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database(); 
    }

    public function index()
    { 
        $query = $this->db->get('tblBuildings');
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            echo $row;
        }
    }
}

/* End of file main.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/main.php */
```

This is what happens when I view main:

> ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

There are 19 rows in the table so I know it's getting something from this (as it echos `Array` 19 times). But other calls do not seem to work. (i.e) `echo $row['id'];`

A `var_dump` on `$query` produces:

> object(CI_DB_pdo_result)#16 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(PDO)#14 (0) { }
>   ["result_id"]=> object(PDOStatement)#15 (1) { ["queryString"]=>
>   string(28) "SELECT * FROM "tblBuildings"" } ["result_array"]=>
>   array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0)
>   ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["row_data"]=> NULL }

There is data in the table, but it doesn't show here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are fetching the row, you get back an array, so echoing it will produce the output you see.

echo is used for primitives, for arrays you should use `print_r` or `var_dump`:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
```